# Why is Faye not working on Android webview control?

Tags: android, webview, faye

Greetings,

I have a page subscribed on faye server. Everything works great on a browser. Now when we placed the web page on an android webview control, Faye is not working at all. We are not receiving any messages from faye. I already enabled the javascript but still not working.

Your help is greatly appreciated,
Best